# Converting Tex file generated by Knitr into .doc

Tags: r, orm, knitr, rstudio, tex

**Why is it important?** My collaborators would like to be able to modify my .pdf reports and they are not able to modify the actual .tex code. They are sooo used to word !

**How I write my reports?** I use knitr. What a great and useful tool; thanks Yihui :)

**What I'm looking for?** convert the generated pdf report into .doc (my collaborators favorite !)

**a solution might help:** Pandoc (http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). As it's explained in the introduction of page of Pandoc, it can be used to convert LaTex to .docx and to markup. I then thought converting the .tex file of each of my reports (a .tex file is generated when I run my knitr .Rnw file) and convert it to .docx using pandoc:

```
pandoc -s myTexRepot.tex -o aDocReport.docx
```

**issue:** 1) Figures are missing in my .docx file. 2) I generate all my tables in my reports using xtable(), none of them can be converted! 3) Also, I lose all table of contents, section numbering.

**Markup to Word:** Issue (1) above is still an issue in converting Markup code to .doc

Is there any better idea to approach the issue of converting latex to doc. If Pandoc is the best, would you know how I can solve the issues above?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The preview version of RStudio has Pandoc integration. See [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html) for documentation on conversion to doc.

Comment: @Ramnath, that's very helpful. Wish there were something similar for .tex

Answer (score 1):

since you are already using knitr, you can call the `rmarkdown:render()` function to knit the document.

there is a parameter in `render()` called `output_format`[1].  the parameter along with the YAML header in your knitr document will allow you do generate the pdf and word document simultaneously

[1] `output_format` 
R Markdown output format to convert to. Pass "all" to render all formats defined within the file. Pass the name of a format (e.g. "html_document") to render a single format or pass a vector of format names to render multiple formats. Alternatively you can pass an output format object; e.g. html_document(). If NULL is passed then the output format is the first one defined in the YAML metadata of the input file (defaulting to HTML if none is specified).